# How to suppress a previously stated CSS rule? (background-color)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap there is a css rule that says

```
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

I would like to suppress the rule `background-color` without overwriting it.
Because if I add this to my custom style.css:

```
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

... the elements will have a white background.

The desired effect is to suppress the line `background-color: #eee;`

To keep the color defined in the class .btn-primary.

The HTML looks like this

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li role="presentation"><a class="btn btn-info" href="#">AAA</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">BBB</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `head` section of your HTML, include your `custom.css` file after `bootstrap.css` and add `!important` after `inherit`.

It should do the trick.

```
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    background-color: inherit !important;
}
```

Or you can use `unset`:

```
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    background-color: unset !important;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/unset

Comment: Sorry, but like explained in my question this makes the element inherit a white background from it's parent which is not the desired effect. The desired effect is not to change the background-color and keep the one defined in another class (btn-xxx)